# Dynamic Authority value for multi-tenant application in .NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, multi-tenant, .net-5

I'm working with a multi-tenant application where we have an `API` project and another `WEB` project (`razor` pages). In this context, each customer (tenant) has a specific database and there is a third project, called `Manager` which is responsible for storing the information of each tenant. Thus, whenever a client accesses one of the projects (`WEB` or `API`) we identify the database and the parameters needed by the tenant based on their domain. For example:

```
client1-api.mydomain.com
client1-web.mydomain.com
client2-api.mydomain.com
client2-web.mydomain.com
```

Because the `WEB` and `API` projects are unique and have multiple databases (one for each tenant), `Identity Server 4` was configured in the WEB project, so that whenever a client needs to connect, it logs in via the WEB project or generate a `JWT token` via the address `{clientname}-web.mydomain.com/connect/token` (for example: `client1-web.mydomain.com/connect/token`).
Thus, the `API` has an `Identity Server 4` authentication and authorization configuration, so that the token generated in the `WEB` project can be used to access its resources.

However, we are not able to make the `Authority` parameter dynamically update on a per-customer basis (the tenant). The initial idea was to build a `middlaware` that checks the connected tenant and loads, through the `Manager`, the `Authority` parameter and set it whenever a request is made. In general, middleware works and the `Authority` parameter is set. However, whenever a client tries to access an `API` resource, the token is invalid and therefore the request is not authorized. Analyzing this problem, I verified that whenever the `API` receives a request, it tries to validate the token in the `WEB` project, but when analyzing the address of the Tenant that is making the request to the `WEB` project, I noticed that it is the same that is set by default in the method `ConfigureServices` and with that, authentication and authorization only works for this default client.

So is there any way to dynamically set the `Identity Server 4` `Authority` in an application with this scenario?

**API Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //other settings
    
    services.AddAuthentication(option =>
    {
        option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://client1-web.mydomain.com";
    });
    
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.RequireClaim("scope", "any1", "any2");
        });
    });
    
    //other settings
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //other settings
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.UseTenantConfig();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers()
            .RequireAuthorization("ApiScope");
    });
    
    //other settings
}
```

**TENANT PARAMETER CONFIGURATION MIDDLAWARE**

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context,
            ITenantParameterService tenantParameterService,
            IOptions<IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions> identityServerAuthenticationOptions)
{
    var tenantInfo = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TenantInfo>(); //Get tenant domain
    var connectionString = tenantParameterService.GetConnectionStringByTenant(tenantInfo.Address);
    var authorityParameter = tenantParameterService.GetParameterByTenant(tenantInfo.Address, "Authority");

    var myContext = context.RequestServices.GetService<MyDbContext>();
    myContext?.Database.SetConnectionString(connectionString);

    identityServerAuthenticationOptions.Value.Authority = authorityParameter;

    await _next(context);
}
```

By executing the code, whenever a request is made in the application, middlaware will update the necessary `parameters`, including the `connection string`. However the problem is: if the token is generated in `client1-web.mydomain.com` to be used in `client1-api.mydomain.com` the authentication works perfectly due to the default configuration at startup (we use this configuration due to the `boostrap` of the application when it starts and even leaving null for it to be set dynamically, the authentication problem persists). Now, if the token is generated in `client2-web.mydomain.com` to be used in `client2-api.mydomain.com` I get the message saying that the token is invalid: `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://client2-web.mydomain.com' is invalid"`. When decoding the token generated in this case, it was possible to notice that it is correct, because the `iss` is like `https://client2-web.mydomain.com` and therefore, the error is in the token and yes in its validation by the `API`.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've seen this question several time today during my research for the same situation and there are never any replies.

Comment: @MViglainco Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution.